# Как убрать программно из словаря парные кавычки

Tags: python

```
    Есть словарь такого вида:
    {
    "'Телефон'": ['"0010"', '"55200"', 'FIO'], "'Телефон'": ['"1010"', '"58200"', 'FIO'],
    "'Телефон'": ['"0010"', '"55200"', 'FIO'], "'Телефон'": ['"1010"', '"58200"', 'FIO']
     }
Как программно убрать двойные кавычки из keys() снаружи и  из value() изнутри.
Спасибо.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант (кстати в Вашем словаре значения ключей не уникальны):

```
my_dict = {"'Телефон'": ['"0010"', '"55200"', 'FIO'], "'Телефон'": ['"1010"', '"58200"', 'FIO'],
           "'Телефон'": ['"0010"', '"55200"', 'FIO'], "'Телефон'": ['"1010"', '"58200"', 'FIO']
           }

my_dict_without_simbol = {}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    new_val = [i.replace('"', '') for i in value]
    new_key = key.strip('\'')
    my_dict_without_simbol[new_key] = new_val

print(my_dict_without_simbol)
```

Вывод:

```
{'Телефон': ['1010', '58200', 'FIO']}
```

Comment: '"998903085015"': ['0015', '163810', 'FIO'] получается так. Но с номера телефона не убирается кавычки